# How to change default path to main Web Host address IIS7

Tags: iis-7

I had to change web servers and upgrade from IIS6 to IIS7.  I have a main page "www.mymainpage.com" and want www.mymainpage.com/default.asp to be it's resolving path when people search for www.mymainpage.com  How do I set this?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

IIS Manager > Select your site > Default Document.

If your default document is called "default.asp", you need to add it and then move default.asp to top of the list.

Comment: Thanks for this info.  I guess this is case sensitive?? because by default "Default.asp" was in the list

Comment: I have a second issue now.  The main page refers to "default.asp" which shows an anonymously authentication accessible page.  However, on that page there is a "login button" that when selected allows the user to login with our domain's windows authentication credentials.  How do I activate this?